# Wifi not working with Ubuntu 12

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I'm a brand new to Linux coming from Windows. I'm soon to be enrolling in a CS class and thought I should get some hands on experience with Linux. So with this being said, I hope I illustrated that I'm not expert with Ubuntu.

## The Problem

I just recently installed Ubuntu 12 and can't seem to establish an internet connection. I clicked the little internet icon on the top right of my screen, and it did not show any local routers or anything whatsoever. I already "googled" about this problem, but I keep seeing the usage of commands in the terminal to "update" and so forth. Problem is, I can't update because I don't have any connection at all. I also read some articles talking about installing drivers, but again, I have absolutely no internet connection.  Like I previously stated before, I'm brand new to Ubuntu, and I could use some help. Thanks!

Comment: try `sudo rfkill unblock all` command on terminal.Then search for the wifi networks.

Comment: Ok, since I only have one device in my home to access the network, I have to dual boot back into Ubuntu. So my response will take a second. ( I'm connected to wifi in windows 7)

Comment: @Avinash Raj, still no luck. Nothing happened, and no change in my internet connection

Comment: post the output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: It doesn't display anything, it just goes back to normal as if I didn't enter a command

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue , what I had to do is reset the BIOS and and then do the sudo rfkill command.

... Also just as a pre measure not trying to challenge your intellect or anything , but just make sure that your wireless availability is turned on. Normally a switch on the hardware or a button with the WAP symbol.

Comment: How could I attempt to reset the BIOS? Is it a setting within the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem once or twice. What worked for me is just manually restarting it. If that doesn't work I would try looking at the settings on your computer. If you know the name of your router and the password you could probably just manually add the server from your connections options. Just go under your internet bar and hit "edit connections" and add a wireless server.